# what (if anything) is wrong with the following SQL? (having and group by)

Tags: sql, group-by, count, having

I bumped into a practice question online, and couldn't find a satisfying answer yet.

Suppose we have two tables that look like these

[Table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VSu7.png)

If that is the case, then what (if anything) is wrong with the following SQL?:

```
SELECT Name
FROM Orders, Salesperson
WHERE Orders.salesperson_id = Salesperson.ID
GROUP BY salesperson_id
HAVING COUNT( salesperson_id ) >1
```

I got this question from https://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/advanced-sql-interview-questions-and-answers/

This link actually has answer and explanation for the question.

I think I understand the explanation, but I still think this query SHOULD run without an error. And the result would be accurate too because there are no duplicate names (salespersonid and name uniquely match 1:1).

Can someone explain to me if I'm wrong and what am I missing here?

Comment: If you make yourself a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) you can quickly create yourself a way to test it.

Comment: This query will only run without error in MySQL 5.6 or older and no other RDBMS. MySQL 5.7 or newer's default behavior is to error out if there is a column in the SELECT portion of the query that isn't being aggregated by a function that isn't also present in the GROUP BY. 5.7 or newer can have `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` option toggled off to behave like older versions. The main issue here is that you are selecting 1 `NAME` for each distinct `salesperson_id`. If there is more than one `NAME` for each distinct `salesperson_id` than mysql (5.6 or older) will just grab one `NAME` at random

Comment: Well, *you* know that there are no duplicate names, but the optimizer doesn 't.

Comment: You say that `Name` and `Salesperson_id` is 1:1, but only you know that, the RDBMS has no idea, so you are relying (hoping really) that the 1:1 holds true for the future as well. Your RDBMS (except mysql 5.6 or older) doesn't trust you. If it is truly 1:1, then `GROUP BY Name` which is what you are intending here anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The database throws an error message because it cannot infer that there is a unique `name` for each `id`.

Some database systems are smart enough for such a deduction, but not all.

Of course you are right that there is an unambiguous result for your query; it's just a case of you being smarter than the artificial intelligence of the query optimizer.

It is actually a good idea not to let the optimizer become too smart: The cycles that are necessary to make such a deduction would have to be expended for *all* queries, including the majority of queries that don't need it.

And it is easy to fix the query, right?